# rails s起動時、LoadErrorになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-spring

### 環境

Rails 5.1.6
ruby 2.6.3

### エラー内容

`rails s` コマンドを入力すると、以下のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。
解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        50: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        49: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        48: from /Users/keisuke/Desktop/Ruby/app/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        47: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        46: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        45: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        42: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        40: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        38: from /Users/keisuke/Desktop/Ruby/app/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        37: from /Users/keisuke/Desktop/Ruby/app/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        36: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
        27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
        26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `start'
        25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:61:in `run'
        24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:14:in `config'
        23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
         9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
         7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
         6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
         5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
         4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
         3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
         2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
         1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle, 0x0009): dependent dylib '/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' not found for '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle' - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: pumaが使おうとしているSSLのライブラリがMySQLのものになっているような感じのエラーログですね。MySQLをアンイストールやバージョンアップしたなどの心当たりはありますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．以前MySQLをバージョンアップしました．MySQLのバージョンを下げると解決されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
gem uninstall puma && gem install puma
```

でpumaを再インストールすると解決するかもしれません。

Comment: pumaを再インストールすることで解決できました。ありがとうございます。